# Parsing .cfm file requests into MVC acceptable urls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, coldfusion, redirect

So here is an old question and probably have its answer already posted. But I was unable to format my query clever enough to find the answer. Please mark as duplicate if anyone knows.

The website is previously a ColdFusion one, and it introduced a Lucid Player plugin which generates links from its own side. But as the website has now moved to ASP.NET MVC structured one with C#, the links which the Lucid Player has generated could obviously not work in the new website. As there are only 5 different pages to link to, I guess that I could try to redirect those HTTP requests to new cshtml files and rewriting the whole page. But How do I parse the request?

I now have five links generated like http://somemainpage/some_template.cfm?someID=151, which only differs in someID number, and I would like to look for a way to parse the request into a controller and view while keeping the number. I tried to edit the routes.Maproutes but it appears they only take in standard MVC requests?

So is there a way to do this in the code? I do noticed that in PHP we can redirect using regex, but how to do similar things in C#? Also, is there a way to parse any specific urls just like what routes.rb did in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: When you use C#, I guess you are on an IIS web server? There's a rewriting module for IIS: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control on the server side. So I'm trying to do it all under ASP.NET MVC structure. But you're right, maybe I have to talk to the website manager. That would really make it easier.